# How did nobles upon the Grand Tour evade or mitigate the danger of banditry?

Tags: crime, early-modern, travel

The era of the [Grand Tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Tour) was rife with banditry; and yet the rite of passage remained popular amongst the aristocracy.

*What reported methods did nobles use to either evade banditry or mitigate the outcome?*

***Popular route for 18th century English nobles:***
[image]
<sub>[Source: Indiana University](http://www.iub.edu/~iuam/online_modules/grand_tour/03_map.php?ptID=3)</sub>

***Example of rural banditry:***
[image]
<sub>[Source: William Powell Frith's 1860 painting of 17th century highwayman Claude Duvall](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:William_Powell_Frith_Claude_Duval.jpg)</sub>

Comment: I guess you mean late 19th century? (as opposite to 18th)

Comment: @Lohoris The Grand Tour as commonly understood was a rite of passage of young nobles from the mid-17th century to the mid-19th century. Whilst the term has been co-opted for European travel before and after this period, the rise of rail, steamboats and an affluent middle class reduced the cachet of this rite of passage by the mid to late 19th century.

Comment: Ok, but in that case the map is wrong: there was no "Kingdom of Italy" back then… (btw the map shows no Corse either)

Comment: @Lohoris Pity. Decent maps of the Grand Tour are hard to find. If you can't trust museum curators - who can you trust? Seems they overlaid the route on top of an anachronistic map.

Comment: What evidence is there that the assertion of "rife with banditry" is true and that these scions were immune to it any more than anyone else?

Comment: @Oldcat It was common everywhere and targeted specifically the wealthy (peasants had nothing). Getting [exact information](http://goo.gl/hXUoCC) is somewhat challenging and hence the question; but we know that brigands, bandits, highwaymen and road agents were common at the time due to wars, taxes, famines and religous persecution. The [list of highwaymen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highwaymen) on Wikipedia is woefully incomplete; but explicit existence of shotgun messengers armed with coach guns plus the creation of traveller's cheques suggest banditry was indeed a serious problem.

Comment: Most of those on the list are in England and not on the Grand Tour route.

Comment: @Oldcat English Wikipedia is predictably Anglo-centric. [Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigantaggio), [French](http://www.criminals.lt/page.php?al=french_banditry) and [German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A4uber) banditry is however not a figment of my imagination; indeed the more complete German article on the [Grand Tour](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Tour) explicitly discusses banditry, if briefly. Naturally being limited to English as my sole language, I have need of _history.se_ members with expertise in the Early Modern Period of Continental Europe.

Comment: The Italian scenes from *The Count of Monte Christo* come to mind.

Comment: My girlfriend the professional historian answered immediately and confidently, "by bringing thugs of their own."

Comment: @LateralFractal - I'm not denying bandits, just don't have any feel for if the 1 Dick Turpin a century caused anyone to change plans any more than the odd murderer in cities keeps everyone at home in terror.

Answer (score 3):

The nobility was the estate of warriors, "those who fight". This tradition hadn't vanished at that time yet. These grand touring nobles knew how to fight, had companions who knew how to fight, and they were escorted by bodyguards who REALLY knew how to fight.

The grand tours were regarded as part of the military education of French young nobles around the 16th and 17th centuries, for example. I read an account of this in the book "Warrior Pursuits: Noble and civil conflict in early modern France". Other Western European countries with traditions of chivalry wouldn't be very different.

Comment: Do you have evidence for these claims? Another point: the Grand Tour is a distinctive term for long tours by young *English* nobles on the Continent.

Comment: This is a little bit past the nobles' sons as 'warrior knights' period and more like Mister Darcy from Pride and Prejudice.  The culture they soaked up was hardly military.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of information on the dangers of the Grand Tour.  I did find this:

> A Tourist would not carry much money due to the risk of highway
>   robbers so letters of credit from their London banks were presented at
>   the major cities of the Grand Tour. Many Tourists spent a great deal
>   of money abroad and due to these expenditures outside of England, some
>   English politicians were very much against the institution of the
>   Grand Tour.

[SOURCE](http://geography.about.com/od/historyofgeography/a/grandtour.htm)